# Adding a column to a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` of all the user's contacts, and I want to add a circle with their first initial in front of each contact's name, like in the google contacts app. I cannot figure out how to add a new column to a `ListView`.

This is what I have in my activity for creating the list:

```
    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private String currentQuery;
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    };
    private static final String[] FROM = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY.substring(0,1), Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { R.id.first_initial, R.id.contact_text };
    private static final String SELECTION = "(" + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP +
        " = 1) AND (" + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 )";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_list_item, null, FROM, TO, 0);
    }
```

It worked fine, then I tried adding the first initial column by adding `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY.substring(0,1),` to `FROM` and adding `R.id.first_initial,` to `TO`. How do I properly add the column?

Answer (score 0):

You must return a View that have that components at the getView of your Adapter.